# Deserialize large result

Tags: c#

I created a simple console application with which I would like to deserialize the result obtained with api, but due to the large number of returned objects, deserialization takes a very long time:

**In Json Result i got list of all products in my shop**

```
"products": [
  {
    "title": "xxxx",
    "id": xxx,
    "created_at": "2021-06-22T10:11:24Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-06-22T10:21:05Z",
    "type": "xxx",
    "status": "xx",
    "downloadable": "xx",

    /*and 20 more keys*/
  },
  {
   /*next product*/
  }
]
```

In my app i want store only few data from result to list.

**I create simple model (with data who i want store):**

```
public class Product
{
  public string id{ get; set; }
  public string code { get; set; }
  public string stock { get; set; }
}
```

**And method for get data from API and deserialize it:**

```
var client = new RestClient("API_URL");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "KEY");
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "KEY");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
List<Product> products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(response.Content);
```

But my Api return aprox 2000 products. When the code is run, deserialization takes about 3 hours (it takes about 10 seconds for the API to return results). Unfortunately, I can't change the number of keys returned by the API. Is it possible to deserialize data faster?

Comment: Have you tried the debugger to see which line takes 3 hours? Deserialization doesn't take that long unless you don't have enough memory available for the processing... but still it wouldn't take 3 hours.

Comment: You've shown us the Product model but you are deserializing ShoperProduct?

Comment: `deserialization takes about 3 hours` - goodness! how large is it, and how much memory do you have?

Comment: @StuartrLC thanks. I make mistake while create this post. In code everythink is ok

Comment: @Jawad i create breakpoint and line with deserialization take aprox 3 hours. I have 16 GB memory. Program use aprox. 300 MB

Comment: There is **definitely** something else happening. 5 seconds to deserialize one record?

Comment: @Rodrigues i using API for get one product and deserialization it take aprox 4 seconds

Comment: I just can't believe the call to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject is taking anywhere near that long. Is there more code involved that is part of what you are timing?

Comment: What is the **exact** length of `response.Content`?

Comment: Instead of debugging did you try recording and logging the duration of deserialization using `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()` ?